# How to play a portion of a sound file in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, audio

I want to play any specific portion of a sound file in C#. for example:
an audio file is of 10 seconds. I want play the sounds that is only within 5 seconds to 8 seconds duration.

so, only a specific part that has a start and end position is the sound file will be played nothing else.

I haven't found any support in C#. can any other API help?

Comment: I will recommend you [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Have you even tried looking for c# audio libraries? I'm sure there are loads out there

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.0 or later, I do recommend working with `MediaPlayer` it's a simple class. Please refer to its documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) ([available on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio)):

```
var file = new AudioFileReader("test.mp3");
// skip the first 15 seconds
file.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
var trimmed = new OffsetSampleProvider(file);
// only play 10 seconds
var takeDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
trimmed.TakeSamples = (int)(trimmed.WaveFormat.SampleRate * takeDuration.TotalSeconds) * trimmed.WaveFormat.Channels;
var player = new WaveOut();
player.Init(new SampleToWaveProvider16(trimmed));
player.Play();
```

Comment: This worked, but i recommend to put the github link instead of the actual because browser doesnt let you open that link without warnings about viruses, etc